# Find all generators for the cyclic group $\mathbb Z_9 \times \mathbb Z_4$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

Find all generators for the cyclic group $\bbmath Z_9 \times \bbmath Z_4?

I know I can use o(9,4)= 36 and all divisors of 36 are 1,2,3,4,6,9,12,18,36. This tells me that I will have subgroups of these orders.

Comment: Since $\gcd(9,4)=1$, $(x,y)$ is a generator if and only if $x$ generates $\mathbb Z_9$ and $y$ generates $\mathbb Z_4$.

Comment: More closely a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1512377/620957

Answer (score 0):

Since $\phi(36)=12$, there are $12$ generators. There are several duplicates on how to find these:

[How to find a generator of a cyclic group?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/786452/how-to-find-a-generator-of-a-cyclic-group)

[Finding all the generators of $Z_{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2504831/finding-all-the-generators-of-z-n?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Find all generators for the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_9 \times \mathbb{Z}_{10}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1512377/find-all-generators-for-the-cyclic-group-mathbbz-9-times-mathbbz-10?rq=1)

A useful fact is the following: if $g$ is a generator of the cyclic group $G$ of order $n$, then $g^{k}$ is a generator if and only if $\gcd(n, k) = 1$.